# Compile a regex with one pattern per line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have multiple patterns to check against. Say `hello` and `bye`, but will be many more, so I chose to use `re.compile()` to store them and then being able to check this regex:

```
import re

mypatt = re.compile(r'(hello|bye)', re.IGNORECASE)
url = ["bye bye", "hello how are you", "i am fine", "ok byeee"]
for u in url:
    if mypatt.search(u):
        print "yes --> %s" %(u)
```

Upon running this code I get the desired output:

```
yes --> bye bye
yes --> hello how are you
yes --> ok byeee
```

However, since there are multiple patterns I would like to write one per line, with something like:

```
mypatt = re.compile(r'(\
    hello|\
    bye\
    )', re.IGNORECASE)
```

However this does not work and I cannot understand why. What is the way to write such statement, writing every pattern in a different line?

Comment: You need the `re.VERBOSE` flag to ignore unescaped whitespace, I think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good one! `re.compile(r"""( ... )""", re.IGNORECASE |re.VERBOSE)` made it. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Using the verbose flag even allows one to enter comments per line.

Comment: @Evert interesting, thanks. I just found a nice example in the [re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) reference.

Comment: Yup, the reference works well here. I see I was mistaken about quoting each line though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a pattern that includes the whitespace at the start of each line. To avoid this, either:

1. Use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent), which removes common leading whitespace from each line in a multiline string; or
2. Add the [`re.VERBOSE` (or `re.X`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) flag to ignore unescaped whitespace and allow the addition of inline comments.